# Add data into Array in local storage, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, local-storage

I'm trying to store the page Id in an array stored in local storage every time a user load a page.

I have my array, it create one if needed but for some reasons it does not update the array in new page load and keeps the first page Id.
I want to add the page id in that array on every page load if the id is not already in that array.
I've tried a lot of things but it seems like I don't understand something, any help ? Thanks

Here is my code

```
    const [isPostId, setItems] = useState([postId]);

  useEffect(() => {
//const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPostId')) == null) {
  localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(isPostId));

}
if (!isPostId.includes(postId)) {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPostId'))
  localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(isPostId));
}  },[isPostId]);
```

EDIT: It works now, looks like I was confused about how localStorage works, now it's clear thanks for your help everyone

Both are working:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const storageKey = "isPostId";
    const json = localStorage.getItem("isPostId");
    const previousPosts = json ? JSON.parse(json) : [];
    const filtered = previousPosts.filter((it) => it !== postId);
    const updatedPosts = [...filtered, postId];

    const stringifyed = JSON.stringify(updatedPosts);
    localStorage.setItem("isPostId", stringifyed);
    console.log('heu',filtered)
  }, [])
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  // options a - full replace
  localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(isPostId));

  // option b - only add unique, don't remove previous
  var currentIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPostId')) || [];
  isPostId.map((e) => {
    if (!currentIds.includes(e) {
      currentIds.push(e);
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(currentIds));
}, [isPostId])
```

Comment: This line `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPostId'))` does nothing by itself.  Do you want to assign that to some variable, maybe call setItems with the result?

Comment: i've wrote this line because I've read online that you need to get the items before writing into it. This if condition is supposed to update the array in isPostId  (wich lives in local storage)  with the variable postId

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, then you need something like this solution.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const storageKey = "isPostId";
    const json = localStorage.getItem("isPostId");
    const previousPosts = json ? JSON.parse(json) : [];
    const updatedPosts = [...previousPosts, ...isPostId];
    const uniquePosts = Array.from(new Set(updatedPosts))
    const stringifyed = JSON.stringify(uniquePosts);
    localStorage.setItem("isPostId", stringifyed);
}, [])
```

Comment: Yeah that's almost the idea, but I have 2 questions:

- what storageKey variable do ?

- How could I check if that Id is already in that array and do nothing if that's the case ? I just want the id to be written once, so I can track wich page has been seen

Comment: "storageKey" is just the key by which data is stored in localStorage. You gave it a name, and I decided to put it in a variable so as not to make a mistake when calling get/set.

Comment: You need to understand whether you just want to not add the key if it already exists or move it to the end of the array. In the first case, you need to check for the presence of a key and decide whether to add it or not. 
const isKeyExist = previousPosts.some((it) => it === postId);
const updatedPosts = isKeyExist ? previousPosts : [...previousPosts, postId];

Comment: In the second case, you have to filter the array and add the value to the end.
const filtered = previousPosts.filter((it) => it !== postId);
const updatedPosts = [...filtered, postId];

Comment: Oooh okay I understand, what I want to do is add the key if it does not exist and then add every post id in the array that is the value of isPostId key

Comment: It took me a while to realize that your state stores an array. In this case, you need to expand it through the spread operator, and then leave only unique values in the array. We can find unique values via "new Set", then save them to localStorage

Comment: I have edited the solution, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the code in the first if statement will put ONE id in local storage if there isn't one already, but not as an array. The code in the second if statement will also only set one id. You need to be setting an array value as shown below

If isPostId is declared as an array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // options a - full replace
  localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(isPostId));

  // option b - only add unique, don't remove previous
  var currentIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPostId')) || [];
  isPostId.map((e) => {
    if (!currentIds.includes(e) {
      currentIds.push(e);
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(currentIds));
}, [isPostId])
```

If isPostId is declared as a string:

If you are certain there will not be single string values in localStorage and there will only be null values or arrays, you can do this as such:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  var currentIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPostId')) || [];

  if (!currentIds.includes(isPostId) {
    currentIds.push(isPostId);
  }

  localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(currentIds));
}, [isPostId])
```

If there is a possibility that there could be individual string values, you will need an additional check for the code inside the useEffect

```js
var currentIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isPostId'));

if (!currentIds?.length) {
  currentIds = [];
} else if (typeof currentIds !== 'object') {
  // value in localStorage is a single string/number rather than an array
  currentIds = [currentIds]
);

if (!currentIds.includes(isPostId) {
  currentIds.push(isPostId);
}

localStorage.setItem('isPostId', JSON.stringify(currentIds));
```

Could simplify the second chunk further if desired

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer,

I've modified it to fit in my UseState, it kinda works, PostId are added in the array but it adds every post Id , even those who are already in

isPostId: "[[238164],[237721],[238164],[239106],[239106]]",

Comment: What is the value of "isPostId"? Is it a string/number or an array? If the value is an array, then what you are experiencing would make sense. In this case, try setting isPostId to be a string instead and then allow the useEffect to handle the array

Comment: In my last comment this is what localstorage saved with the key isPostId where in the array is stored the post id (always number) . The post id come from the variable postId

Comment: But yeah  isPostid key refers to an array

Comment: Does the initial declaration of the useState have to be an array? That is the cause to this issue

Comment: No it does not, i've wrote it that way becase i tought I had to

Comment: If you want to keep it as an array, I updated my answer to have a case for that. The case for the array is at the top. If you convert isPostId to always be a string, you can use the previous options I offered!